# WebSockets with TeamCity behind Amazon ELB

Tags: proxy, amazon-elb, teamcity, websocket

I'm setting up TeamCity behind a public ELB in Amazon. I am attempting to fix the WebSocket connection issue:

`Some users cannot use optimized web UI updates via WebSocket protocol.`

This is a standard, default install of TeamCity listening on port 8111 with an ELB that terminates HTTPS (TLS) on port 443 at the ELB. I'm able to access the TeamCity service just fine.

My searches came up for people who were trying to use NGINX, or Apache in front of TeamCity, but that is *not* what I am trying to do. I've even enabled the AWS ELB ProxyProtocol Policy on the backends.

Is there some secret sauce to having TeamCity successfully use WebSockets directly through an ELB where the HTTPS connection gets terminated there?

I feel like I am missing something here, and the documentation only helps if I'm using a reverse proxy in front.

Comment: The ELB needs to be an Applicatiin Load Balancer (ELB 2.0) not Classic (ELB 1.0) for web socket support in HTTP mode.  Is that what you are using?

Comment: Since WebSockets uses a long-lived connection (after the initial HTTP request to upgrade to the WebSocket protocol), you might try configuring your ELB to terminate TCP/TLS on port 443, and then uses TCP to the backend instance port 8111.